# Percentiles of a distribution of weighted summary statistics

Tags: descriptive-statistics, quantiles, convolution

Suppose I have a collection of different independent probability distributions, $\{ P_i(X)\}_{i=1}^N$, each with their own support $I_i$. I know that the $10^{th}$ percentile of a given distribution is given as $x_i^{10} | 0.1 = \int_{\inf(I_i)}^{x_i^{10}} P_i(x)dx$ and the average (mean) of the $10^{th}$ percentile of the distribution would be $ y_i = \int_{\inf(I_i)}^{x_i^{10}} xP(x) dx$. I could then take all the mean $10^{th}$ values and create a distribution of those values $Q(Y)$, the $10^{th}$ percentile of this distribution would be $y_k$ for the largest $k$ that satisfies $0.1 \geq \sum_{i=0}^k Q(y_i)$. Is there a meaningful way to relate this statistic back to a percentile of the combination of all the distributions, i.e. $P(X) = P_1 * P_2 * \cdots * P_N$. My intuition would tell me that that $y_k$ would be an upper bound of the $1^{st}$ percentile of $P$, but I don't know how to prove this right or wrong. If there is anything off in previous statements of this question please correct my misconceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of question where it can be useful to try some experiments before proving anything.

Try uniform distributions on $[0,1]$.  The $q$th quantile of each distribution is just $q$, but for moderate $N$ the distribution of the sum is very close to Normal. I'll take $N=12$ so that the distribution of the sum is close to $\mathcal{N}(6,1)$. The $q$th quantile of this is $6+\Phi^{-1}(q)$, where $\Phi$ is the Normal CDF and the sum of the $q$th quantiles is $12q$. We can see that for large $q$ (say, 0.95) the sum of the quantiles ($12\times 0.95$) is larger than the quantile of the sum ($6+1.96$). For small quantiles (say 0.05), the sum of the quantiles ($0.05\times 12$) is *less* than the quantile of the sum ($6-1.96$), and they agree at $q=0.5$.  So, there seems to be a bound, but it's very far from sharp, and the direction of the bound depends on which quantile you're looking at.

Something *like* this will be true fairly generally, because the sum of the quantiles will increase proportional to $N$ (exactly if the distributions are the same, and in some approximate handwavy way if they aren't), but the quantile of the sum will only increase like $N\mu+\sigma\sqrt{N}$ (by Chebyshev's inequality), where $\mu$ is the mean of the sum and $\sigma$ its standard deviation.  More generally (assuming reasonable tail behaviour), the sum will be approximately $\mathcal{N}(N\mu, N\sigma^2)$.

Comment: When you say $N(N\mu,N\sigma^2)$ is the first $N$ referring to a normal distribution?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  (I didn't choose either set of notation)